# Таблица тегов GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs

Вводная - GNU Emacs 23, дистрибутив Debian Squeeze. Не могу найти файл с таблицей тегов. Подскажите, где искать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cам разобрался. Оказалось нужно его самому создать в нужном каталоге при мощи команды **ctags/etags** можно прямо из GNU Emacs. Более подробно можно почитать в Emacs'е, набрав **C-h i m Emacs m Tags**. Надеюсь кому-нибудь еще пригодится. Штука в общем нужная.

Comment: скорее всего создать его нужно в каталоге /emacs/src

Comment: @ХэшКод, примите мой ответ.